# MBR2GPT states "wrong boot partition count, expected 1 but found 0"

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I don't know what happened to my drive environment and cannot convert MBR to GPT, with `mbr2gpt` stating I don't have a boot partition:

```
Info    MBR2GPT was explicitly asked to run in full OS mode.
Info    MBR2GPT: Attempting to validate disk 0
Info    MBR2GPT: Retrieving layout of disk
Info    MBR2GPT: Initial partition information
Info    ===========================================================
Info    Partition layout for disk: 0
Info    Partition style          : MBR
Info    MBR signature: 3309446813
Info    Number of partitions     : 2
Info    ===================PARTITION===============================
Info         Number: 1
Info           Type: 7
Info           Boot: No
Info     Recognized: Yes
Info          Style: 0
Info         Offset: 1048576
Info         Length: 197003647488
Info         Volume: \\?\Volume{c542269d-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
Info          Drive: C:\
Info        NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition1
Info    ===================PARTITION===============================
Info         Number: 2
Info           Type: 7
Info           Boot: No
Info     Recognized: Yes
Info          Style: 0
Info         Offset: 197005410304
Info         Length: 315102330880
Info         Volume: \\?\Volume{c542269d-0000-0000-0000-70de2d000000}\
Info          Drive: D:\
Info        NT Path: \Device\HardDisk0\Partition2
Info    ===========================================================
Info    ESP partition size will be 104857600
Info    MBR2GPT: Validating layout, disk sector size is: 512 bytes
Error     ValidateLayout: Wrong boot partition count, expected 1 but found 0.
Error     Disk layout validation failed for disk 0
```

I checked my drives in Disk Management, where Disk 0 doesn't have a System Reserved Partition, but Disk 2 does; I'm really confused if it was left a long time ago when I installed a system on it: 
 [image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably talking about an [EFI system partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) (ESP) which is required for Windows on a GPT disk to boot. You need to either shrink `C:` or `D:` to get at least 100MiB, the size the program seems to expect, for that. (Perhaps one on `Disk 2` by shrinking `E:` or `F:` can do as well. Not sure.) You can right click on a partition in Disk Management to shrink it.

No idea if it requires you to create it yourself in advance. If it does, you can try [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-efi), which will work only if the disk is already a GPT disk though, according to the documentation (while MS docs are often unreliable). It that does not work, you may use `fdisk` (and `mkfs.fat`) on e.g. a "live" Linux to do it. Make sure you set the type code to `ef`.

I am not sure how well this program works, so I'd suggest that you shrink `D:` by 1M (again, with Disk Management, which is probably the safest and best way to shrink an NTFS-formatted partition) or so anyway, so that when the backup GPT is written to the end of the disk, it doesn't cause any destruction to the filesystem on `D:`.

Also check out the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di) of `bcdboot` in case the program does not install the UEFI variant of Windows Boot Manager to the newly created ESP for you. Make sure you use it with `/f UEFI` explicitly specified, and have that installed before rebooting after the conversion, because the BIOS variant (which is apparently on `Disk 2`) will not be able to boot the installation on `C:` / `Disk 0` anymore.

---

Edit: Perhaps you should instead use `diskpart` to create a primary partition on `Disk 0` with the space you got after shrinking and mark it as `active` and see. If it still doesn't work, format it to NTFS and use `bcdboot C:\Windows /f BIOS /s X:` (use the drive letter of the new partition for X) to install a BIOS variant of Windows Boot Manager to it, then try to reboot by legacy booting `Disk 0` instead of `Disk 2` in your UEFI boot menu. (They won't be shown as such there though. Figure out yourself which is which, by identifying the vendor/model of them in their device info or so.)

You can also simply do `bcdboot C:\Windows /f BIOS /s C:` and mark `C:` as active instead, although I have no idea what this stupid program will do to `C:` in that case.

You might also need to do:

```
bootsect /nt60 X:
bootsect /nt60 X: /mbr
```

---

P.S. Forget about converting the system disk to GPT disk if your board has BIOS instead of UEFI, as you will never be able to boot Windows-on-GPT with BIOS.

Comment: MBR2GPT is supposed to do everything required to convert from MBR to GPT in order to allow a UEFI boot

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's just too stupid to ignore the fact that the current Windows Boot Manager is on another disk, or that `Disk 0` does not have a partition with the active flag, while neither of those is technically relevant. Both can be remedied with similar approach with `diskpart` / `bcdboot`.

Comment: It was designed to support a disk that was using the recommended partition layout.  If the disk is using a different layout then third-party software will have to be used.  It’s not a matter of “being stupid” it’s just not the right software for the job.  The author could fix the partition layout easily enough though then run the tool

Comment: It is, to me, for the fact that it has requirement on things that is irrelevant to what it does. (Could be Windows itself not providing better means for it to determine certain things that it can more or less deduce from that though.) `It was designed to support a disk that was using the recommended partition layout.` That was really a nice way of saying "don't expect it to be smart/adaptive (enough)".

Comment: Appears that this likely is caused by an invalid BCD less than MBR2GPT, while I agree third-party could be used, fixing the BCD might be easier

Comment: One of the easiest ways to shrink a partition is via `DiskPart`: `shrink desired=103 minimum=100` _(100MB RAW size is 102.4)_

Comment: Do Windows users love CLI as well these days? ;o) (AFAIK Windows calculate in MiB most of the time; they just call it MB; that's why I use the ambiguous M)

Comment: Thanks everything in advance ☺️.

Comment: Before your answers I tried to move the system reserved partition to Disk:0 but with a mistake I deleted the system reserved partition and can not boot anymore. I have no idea to fix it and I reinstalled windows eventually.

Comment: After I reinstalled windows, the disk is still MBR and no system reserved partition there. This time my MBR2GPT works fine with all other disks unplugged. Finally I have a GPT disk and a EFI boot partition.